# How to replace comma between brackets in a string?

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, gsub

I need edit a data.frame in R where some variables are string by [xx xx xxx] format. I tried by gsub function (unsuccessfully).

Example:

```
aux = '1233,[9 087],03/10/1951,[437 ab 345] ,"ab c", [ 001     ab ]'
gsub("\\[(.*),(.*)\\]","[\\1 \\2]", aux)
```

Objective: replace spaces only between brackets data to commas.

```
"1233,[9,087],03/10/1951,[437,ab,345] ,\"ab c\", [001,ab]"
```

...but, the results with gsub code above is that:

```
[1] "1233,[9 087],03/10/1951,[437 ab 345] ,\"ab c\", [ 001     ab,]"
```

Note that the sizes of the spaces are irregular. The idea is replace all spaces into brackets "[]" to a comma ",", except the spaces before the first and after the last character.

How can I do it?

Comment: I can get `1233,[9,087],03/10/1951,[437,ab,345] ,"ab c", [ 001,ab ]` but I guess you want to trim the values inside `[...]`, right?

Comment: Do you need to trim the values inside the `[...]`? Or is above output OK?

Comment: Use `.*?` in place of `.*`

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Is the original item structure  between brackets separated by spaces? If so, you can gsub with `(?<=\\[)[^\\]]*(?=\\])` then in the callback do another gsub on the core using `(?<=[a-z])[ ]+(?=[a-z])` replace with `,`

Comment: @sln Yes, separated by spaces, but in a somewhat unstructured way. Sometimes as the [xx xx] form, sometimes as the [xx         xx  x] form (multiples spaces), sometimes as the [  xx xx    ] form (spaces before before the first and after the last character).

Comment: @LukStorms found a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the spaces you need to replace with a comma have no nested or other square brackets inside, you may use a PCRE regex with `gsub`:

```
aux = '1233,[9 087],03/10/1951,[437 ab 345] ,"ab c", [ 001     ab ]'
res = gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\[\\s*)[^][\\s]*\\K\\s++(?!])(?=[^][]*])", ",", aux, perl=TRUE)
cat(res, "\n")
## => 1233,[9,087],03/10/1951,[437,ab,345] ,"ab c", [ 001,ab ]
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/Geasv7') and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6ZxAp0/1).

Here is an explanation:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\[\s*)` - the location after the last successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or the `[` and zero or more whitespaces
- `[^][\s]*` - 0+ chars other than `]`, `[` and whitespaces
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `\s++` - 1+ whitespaces matched possessively (no backtracking into the pattern, and the next negative lookahead will be only checked after the last whitespace matched)
- `(?!])` - there must be no `]` immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?=[^][]*])` - there must be 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` immediately to the right of the current location

If you consider a non-base R approach, I can recommend `gsubfn`:

```
library(gsubfn)
rx <- "\\[([^][]+)]"
aux = '1233,[9 087],03/10/1951,[437 ab 345] ,"ab c", [ 001     ab ]'
gsubfn(rx, function(g1) paste0("[",gsub("\\s+", ",", trimws(g1)),"]"), aux)
## => [1] "1233,[9,087],03/10/1951,[437,ab,345] ,\"ab c\", [001,ab]"
```

Here, `\\[([^][]+)]` matches substrings that start with `[`, then have 1+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`, and once these matches are found, Group 1 subvalue is trimmed with `trimws()` and all 1+ whitespace chunks are replaced with a comma (with `gsub("\\s+", ",", trimws(g1))`).

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in 2 steps.
And less awesome than the solution from regex-master Wiktor.

Some assumptions were made for the sake of simplicity.

- It's just spaces, not other whitespace characters (--> not using `\s`)
- Just letters and numbers between those spaces (--> using `\w`)

```r
aux = "1233,[9 087],03/10/1951,[437 ab 345] ,\"ab c\", [ 001     ab ]"

# remove the spaces after a "[" or before a "]"
result = gsub("(?<=\\[) +| +(?=\\])", "", aux, perl=TRUE)

# find a "[". Reset and look for spaces followed by word characters. 
# And replace those matches by a comma and the word characters
result = gsub("(?:\\[ *\\w+\\K|\\G) +(\\w+)", ",\\1", result, perl=TRUE)

cat(result, "\n")
```

An R-Fiddle can be found [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=RfsFpRFD&version=2)

Comment: Solved! Thank you!
What is "\\K  and \\G in the code?

Comment: @MarceloFernandes  A `\K` is telling the regex not to add what's already found before in the match result. Thus it looks for that bracket but because that reset doesn't consume it, it's not marked for the replace.  The `\G` is telling the regex to look further after the position of the previous successful match. It's rarely used, but for this it works fine.